# React doesn't see mapped props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this message in browser:
**TypeError: data.map is not a function**

I am passing an array from another component here as props. What I am doing wrong?
Thank you in advance!

**EDITED**:

**event-data.js**

```
const months = ['January', 'February', 'March'];
const eventType = ['Party', 'Karaoke', 'Concert'];

const monthObject = [
  { id: 'sort-by-month' },
  { name: 'By month' },
  { values: months },
];

const eventObject = [
  { id: 'sort-by-category' },
  { name: 'By category' },
  { values: eventType },
];

const eventData = { monthObject, eventObject };
```

**event-filter-bar.js**

```
import eventData from '../../data/event-data';

class EventFilterBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <FilterToolbar data={eventData} />
    );
  }
}
```

**filter-toolbar.js**

```
class FilterToolbar extends Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    return (
      <ButtonToolbar className="justify-content-center">
        <DropdownMaker data={data} />
        <DropdownWithDate />
        <ResetButton />
      </ButtonToolbar>
    );
  }
}

FilterToolbar.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};
```

**dropdown-maker.js**

```
class DropdownMaker extends Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    const eventFilters = data.map((e) => (
      <DropdownMenu
        id={e.id}
        name={e.name}
        values={e.values}
        key={e.id}
      />
    ));
    return (
      { eventFilters }
    );
  }
}

DropdownMaker.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: Can you paste the code where you are using this component?

Comment: `console.log(data)` and you will know

Comment: My guess is that the `data` array that you pass in as a prop doesn't exist at first, and it crashes your app.

Comment: Sorry, I am new in React

Here what I see in console:

Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `RouteComponent`, expected a single ReactElement type.
    in RouteComponent (at navigation-route.js:24)

Comment: @RossAllen already added. Give me a hint, please

Answer (score 1):

Check if the data is actually populated or not before `map` through it.

```
class DropdownMaker extends Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    const eventFilters = (data && data.length > 0) && data.map((e) => (
      <DropdownMenu
        id={e.id}
        name={e.name}
        values={e.values}
        key={e.id} //<-- don't forget to add a unique key prop while use loop
      />
    ));
    return (
      { eventFilters }
    );
  }
}

DropdownMaker.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};
```

Feel free to comment if it's not working.

Comment: You can improve this code by using optional chaining.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.